# Add a password to PDF files generated by Phantomjs

Tags: pdf, phantomjs

I've got some server-side `node.js` code that generates PDF files on request, using `phantomJS`, and I'm looking for a way to add password protection to the output.

Sadly I haven't found any mention of such an option in phantom, which makes sense because Chrome doesn't provide that either. Alternately I could run some other tool that would take the PDF created by phantom and add password protection to it, but I can't seem to find any that can do exactly that (add a password to an existing file) and that's completely free to use (preferably, non-GPL).

Will be happy for suggestions on how to approach this task. Thanks!

Comment: No, that doesn't seem possible with PhantomJS alone. So, this question essentially asks for such a tool. Questions involving the recommendation of software tools or other resources are off-topic on StackOverflow. This is because there is no universally accepted answer when these kinds of questions are asked, which can ultimately attract spam and dissension. Please read the following page on what kinds of questions you can ask: [stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [node-qpdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qpdf) package to encrypt and decrypt PDFs. It makes use of qpdf. So first you need to convert HTML -> PDF then PDF -> Password Protected PDF.