# How to protect an existing PDF file with password using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, encryption

How to protect PDF file with a password using nodejs? without using pdfq or any CLI commands, is that possible ?

im generating an html template to pdf using pdf-creator-node. the output of it, i want to protect it with password.

here is the initial code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const pdfCreator = require("pdf-creator-node");
const data = require("./utils/data");

// Read the HTML template
const htmlTemplate = fs.readFileSync(
  "./templates/html/template.html",
  "utf8"
);

// Define the options for the PDF generation
const options = {
  format: "A4",
  orientation: "portrait",
};

// Compile the HTML template and generate the PDF
const document = {
  html: htmlTemplate,
  data, // Optional data to pass to the template
  path: "output.pdf", // Specify the output file path
};

pdfCreator
  .create(document, options)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("PDF created successfully");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error creating PDF:", error);
  });
```

Comment: no, it's not possible, since `pdf-creator-node` is just a very light front end to `node-html-pdf` which uses `phantomjs`, and that can't do passworded PDF according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719673/add-a-password-to-pdf-files-generated-by-phantomjs

Comment: then can u suggest another approach ?

Comment: well, the question I linked to suggests using `node-qpdf` ... assuming thats the same thing you specifically don't want to use (i.e. `pdfq`), then, no, I have no suggestions for another approach

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76530108/i-need-to-encrypt-existing-pdf-file-with-password-protect-without-qpdf-in-nodejs/